Need help to install a package in Mathematica
today I just downloaded the trial version of Mathematica for 15 days. I am completely new to CAS (Computer Algebra System) and have never used any CAS before, so I am not able to express everything. The problem is I want to know how to install this package in Mathematica. In one of my posts, I asked Mariusz Iwaniuk how to install the package. They replied, "Download 2 files: MultipleZetaValues-1.2.0.paclet and Installation guide 1.20.pdf and read the PDF file on how to install." However, I am unable to find both files.
here is the link of the package
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357601353_Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues

You need to scroll down a little. Then you will find the download buttons for these files.

@HenrikSchumacher thanks, but now method 1 failed and in method I did not what they mean by =Suppose the file is in the following path on your computer:
C:\foldername1\foldername2\foldername3\MultipleZetaValues-1.2.0.paclet

Please read Trouble installing the package MultipleZetaValues.

Does this answer your question? Trouble installing the package MultipleZetaValues

@Domen Thanks for commenting, but when I download the file, it's named "MultipleZetaValues-1.2-4.0." Is this the file I should rename?

Yes. If you are using Windows, you probably don't see the extensions (.zip). Turn them on in the File Explorer under the menu View, in the Show/hide group, select the File name extensions check box. Then, you should see the extension .zip, which you should rename.

@Domen I am using a MacBook Pro, so do I need to do the same?

Show or hide filename extensions on Mac

@Domen still not working

Here is the image of the zip file which I renamed https://ibb.co/PWMftKM

I can confirm that macos' native archiving tool does not allow to unpack the file Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues.zip that I get from the download. Maybe the file is broken. Or maybe you simple have to install an archiving tool that is able to unpack the zip archive.

@HenrikSchumacher, I didn't need to unpack anything. This .zip file is actually a .paclet file, so you just rename it, and Mathematica should be able to process it ...

@Domen Are you also using a MacBook? Because it's not working on my MacBook.

Can you please be more specific about what is not working? Did you rename the file? Did you use PacletInstall with the full path to the file? What error message did you get?

@Domen I changed the file name as you mentioned, but after renaming, when I used this command PacletInstall["path-to-file/Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues.paclet"], I got a $failed error.

You did replace the path-to-file, right? So PacletInstall["/Users/aryan/Documents/Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues.paclet"]

@Domen thank you very much, its working now, again really thanks a lot
